# Current email invocations count by org

Tags: email, governorlimits

I have developed a pretty cool, reusable piece of apex code that allows a user to define which fields on a given object that are of interest when field values change.  When a field changes on an object that a user is interested in, the change data is archived to a custom object and an email is sent out.  I am hitting the limit of 1,000 apex emails per day.  I was wondering if there was a way to take a proactive approach to monitor the number of emails sent in a 24 hour period.  I see there is a Limits apex class but that only shows the current count for a given transaction.  Does anyone know of a method that I can use to get the current count of emails send in a 24 hour period rather than me writing something that is custom to keep track of a count?  I can't believe SFDC limits us to only 1,000 emails.  Kinda defeats the purpose of doing real time alerting via email.  I read somewhere I may be able to create an internal email in SFDC that doesn't count against this limit.  I may have to do that instead if I can't find a viable work around.  Thanks, Ryan

Answer (score 1):

Problem is that you are setting up your email request as external address rather than email your internal users instead.

> You can send an unlimited amount of email to your organization’s internal users, which includes portal users.
>   [Resource Link](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_gov_limits.htm#email_limits_section)

Correct way to doing it:

```
Messaging.SingleEmailMessage emailMsg = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();  
emailMsg.setTargetObjectId(internalUserId);
//must be false if sending to internal user    
emailMSg.saveAsActivity = false; 
emailMsg.setSenderDisplayName('sender name');  
emailMsg.setSubject('some subject');  
emailMsg.setBccSender(false);  
emailMsg.setUseSignature(false);  
emailmsg.setPlainTextBody('email body');  
Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] { emailMsg });
```

[Resource Link](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums?id=906F000000091DkIAI)